# Netbeans IDE tutorials

Tags: java, netbeans, ide

I mostly use Eclipse but have mentionned Netbeans on my cv. Are there any good concise and up-to-date tutorials apart from the official ones that could bring me up to speed on how to use the IDE efficiently (shortcuts, debugging, views ...)? This excludes programming tutorials as I don't really need them unless there's a special manipulation involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at this [cheatsheet](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/24519036/Highlights-of-NetBeans-IDE-65-Keyboard-Shortcuts-Code-Templates)  and this [cheatsheet](http://www.scribd.com/doc/24065387/DZone-Refcardz-14-NetBeans-Java-Editor-6-8)

Comment: Exactly the sort of stuff I was looking for! As derivation says, the official pages have the richest information but it's not necessarily something you can sift through in less than a week.

Answer (score 2):

From within NetBeans, go to **Help -> Keyboard shortcuts card** to see all the main shortcuts.
In the same menu, you have a link to the Help, which contains good explanation for how to use the debugger.

There's also the online help link, with links to many tutorials, including video ones.

Also, most of the content of [Pro NetBeans IDE](http://books.google.com/books?id=cw56y1WQp0IC&printsec=frontcover&dq=netbeans&ei=BVbPS-_OOZG6Ne2jkdEB&cd=2#v=onepage&q&f=false) 6 can be viewed online in Google Books.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a good idea to specify that your question relates to the [Netbeans IDE](http://netbeans.org/), as opposed to the [Netbeans Platform](http://platform.netbeans.org/). The latter is the rich client platform on which the IDE is built (analogous to [Eclipse RCP](http://www.eclipse.org/home/categories/rcp.php)).

Answer (score 1):

The official NetBeans page really is the best place to find NetBeans information; I found it the most helpful when I was learning the platform/ide. Aside from that, however, there are a lot of great articles about Netbeans and it's ecosystem in the [NetBeans Zone](http://netbeans.dzone.com/) at Dzone.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.scribd.com/doc/24065387/DZone-Refcardz-14-NetBeans-Java-Editor-6-8